# Android gradle buildTypes: Duplicate class

Tags: android, build, gradle, source-sets

I'm converting my app to use gradle, and I'm trying to use the buildTypes. I have a `Constants` class which I wish to modify for my release build. So I have a file at `src/main/java/my/package/name/Constants.java` and at `src/release/java/my/package/name/Constants.java`.

When I try to build this, gradle tells me the build failed on the `Constants` file in my release buildtype, with the error that it's a duplicate class.

I also tried adding a different sourceSet for this in my `build.gradle` like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java'];
        //...
    }
    release {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/release/java'];
    }
}
```

But this still gives me the same error. So I'm wondering, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can not have a class in `main` and `release`. You need to split it into something like `debug` and `release`.

gradle will merge the source sets for each `buildType` with `main`.
This is the reason, why the class gets duplicated in your `release` build.

So the rule is: put a class into `main`, or in **every** `buildType` but not both.

Comment: If one put class A in buildType paid and free, main complains about missing class A. How do one handle it?

Comment: Documentation says it possible to override class with same package name and class name https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants but it's not working :(

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the docs say that you can have same class with same class name/ package name **if they are in different flavors**. Not so if one is in `main` and another is in a flavor.

Comment: @tir38 The docs here are clear [about the flavors and duplicate classes](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#sourceset-build).

Comment: Use dynamic class loading and an interface to load the class if it exists on the flavor.

Comment: There are ways to replace the main sourceset(main dir) for different build types?

Answer (score 0):

The answer from "fix" helped me on the way, but I got an error from the main Gradle, saying a constant was missing (in my class Config). This since I had my class only in paid and free version and not in main. Could not find the Config class.
Im not sure if this is a bug in Studio... I finally solved it with the following:

```
buildTypes {

    release {
        ...
        buildConfig "public static final boolean XYZ = false;"
    }

}
```

And the instead of using my Config.XYZ class constant I used buildConfig.XYZ

Comment: or just `buildConfigField "boolean", "XYZ", "false"`