# Product Flavor: Duplicate class found

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, android-productflavors

I have a question, but I'm sitting here in front of my app since hours but I can't understand what the problem is.

I have an android app (written in kotlin) and I want to make two product flavors and override a class / file in the product flavor:

So my gradle script is that:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'


android {
  ...
  productFlavors {
    foo {
      applicationId "com.foo"
    }
  }
}
```

My files are structured as follows:

```
 - src
    - androidTest
    - foo
      - java
        - com
          - example
            - Bar.kt
    - main
      - java
        - com
          - example
            - Bar.kt
    - test
```

So basically I would like to override `Bar.kt` file in `foo` product flavor, but somehow it doesn't work: It says class Bar is duplicated.

Any hint?

Comment: Shouldn't flavor-specific sources exist only in the falvors you've defined (i.e. not in main)? So you'd define at least two flavors, and only have Bar.kt in the source sets for those flavors.

Comment: Hm, maybe you are right ... actually I am trying to override a dagger module ... so `Bar.kt` is actually a Dagger 2 module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android gradle buildTypes: Duplicate class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782368/android-gradle-buildtypes-duplicate-class)

Comment: You can check out my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563632/common-code-for-different-android-flavors/66141092#66141092

Comment: There are some use cases for this. I still want the class in the flavor module to be prioritized and the one in main be ignored.

Answer (score 70):

[The documentation for variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#sourceset-build) states (emphasis mine):

> Note: For a given build variant, Gradle throws a build error if it
>   encounters two or more source set directories that have defined the
>   same Java class. For example, when building a debug APK, you cannot
>   define both src/debug/Utility.java and src/main/Utility.java. This is
>   because Gradle looks at both these directories during the build
>   process and throws **a 'duplicate class' error**. If you want different
>   versions of Utility.java for different build types, you can have each
>   build type define its own version of the file **and not include it in
>   the main/ source set**.

So the solution is to have it's own version of `Bar.kt` per variant and exclude it from main source set.

Comment: If I have say 4-5 flavours, and 3 of them use the same class and the set use specific code, do I need to duplicate it everywhere or sourceSets can do it?
Not able to do with source sets

Comment: @AkhilDad I guess you could create a separate module to share the code across flavours.

Comment: Or add another flavour dimension for that.

Answer (score 35):

As stated by miensol you cannot put your file to `main` and flavor specific folders and expect gradle to work the same way android resource system works. But I found a way to do this without code duplication so you don't have to copy your `Bar.kt` to every flavor folder you have.

So let's say you have three flavors **dev**, **prod** and **mock**. You want your special mocked `Bar.kt` in **mock** but the normal implementation in **dev** and **prod** flavors. You put your mocked file to the **mock** flavor specific folder `mock/java/com/something/` and you put your "default" implementation to new folder with some random name like `non-mock/java/com/something/` naming it something like "common" would also make sense. Now you have to tell gradle where should those flavors look for their `Bar.kt` class.

Put this in to your `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        prod {
            java.srcDirs('src/non-mock/java')
        }
        dev {
            java.srcDirs('src/non-mock/java')
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, using AS 3.4.2. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

If you have multiple flavors, Like A, B and C

and your main code contains all activities, and for A and C flavor you want to change some functionality of some activity ex- ShoppingCartActivity

then you need to make some changes as below, put ShoppingCartActivity in all three flavors (including B as well) and **remove from main** and declare the file into all manifest file other than main manifest

for more details check [Build with source sets](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#sourceset-build)

```
- A
  - java
    - com
      - example
        - ShoppingCartActivity.kt(some changes)

- B
  - java
    - com
      - example
        - ShoppingCartActivity.kt

- C
  - java
    - com
      - example
        - ShoppingCartActivity.kt(new changes added)

- main
  - java
    - com
      - example
        **(remove from here)**
```

Comment: is there any way to use a base of ShoppingCartActivity on main and in case I have another one inside other flavor so I use the flavor one instead?