# Android Gradle fails to override - different versions of same class for different build types

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

In the past, the rule was:
put a class into **main**, or in **every** buildType, **but not both**

[ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698863/build-flavors-for-different-version-of-same-class) and [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782368/android-gradle-buildtypes-duplicate-class)

But the current doc clearly says that Gradle now supports overriding, if the same file exists in different sourceSets (e.g., main and debug):

> If different source sets contain different versions of the same file,
>   Gradle uses the following priority order when deciding which file to
>   use (source sets on the left override the files and settings of source
>   sets to the right):
>
> build variant > build type > product flavor > main source set >
>   library dependencies

from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html).

But it doesn't work! It still complains about "duplicate" classes if you have `foo.java` present in both `main` and `release` folders! Anyone has any idea whether this is a bug in android studio or gradle or just a mistake on their docs?

Comment: My assumption is that it is a mistake in the docs.

Comment: I think it's referencing things like `strings.xml` and other assets, but Java classes still have to be defined individually.